# Are there shortcut keys for ReSharper's Unit Test Runner?

Tags: unit-testing, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, command

For obvious productivity reasons, I make an effort of learning and using as many of the keyboard shortcuts for the various Re# commands.

However, it seems that the unit test runner does not have any associated shortcut keys. I want to be able to select certain tests and be able to run or debug them without resorting to grabbing the mouse each time. Is using the mouse my only option?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

ReSharper adds items to Visual Studio's keyboard settings dialog box.

Go to:

> Tools -> Options, Environment ->
>   Keyboard

In the search bar, type "resharper" and see the vast options that you can control with the keyboard.

Specifically, there is one to launch the unit test explorer window, and there's a couple called

- ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunSolution
- ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunContext

that are likely what you need.

Comment: and in another note, I don't use this... I map CTRL+T to TestDriven.NET.

Comment: Ctrl+T now maps to 'Go to type' in R#, so I ended up using Alt+T as an alternative.

Comment: Even - I thinks that's when you choose to preserve VS key bindings, which I don't.  In fact, most R# users I know choose the R# key bindings, as they seem to feel more natural (at least to me)

Comment: unfortunately this activates the unit test session window, so when i want to continue coding, I have to switch back to the code window... :(

Comment: Handy shortcut.  There ought to be a default for this.

Comment: As of R# 2023 these seem to be called `ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTestRunSolution` and `ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTestRunFromContext`

Answer (score 25):

You could try ... <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>

 - if your cursor is in the Test method, then R# just runs that test

 - if its in a test class, but not a method, R# runs all the tests in the class

Comment: Nice if you do last one D then you have debug!

Answer (score 18):

As for running all tests in solution the command is Alt-RUN, i.e. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for ReSharper menu, <kbd>U</kbd> for Unit Testing, and <kbd>N</kbd> for all tests in solution.

And if you're using the R# shortcuts, the chord Ctrl-U, L will always do the job.

NOTE: I found this answer from from stackoverflow user [ilya-ryzhenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18575/ilya-ryzhenkov) on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334933/resharper-run-all-unit-tests-in-a-project-or-solution-at-once)

Comment: that's fairly easy to memorize :)

Answer (score 18):

### Resharper > 7 / Visual Studio 2012

You can find them in the defined shortcuts in Visual Studio 2012 under
[Tools] > [Options] > [Environment] > [Keyboard]

I usually use these:

```
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| Description                     | Shortcut       |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
| Run Test in Debug Mode (Editor) | Ctrl+U, Ctrl+D |
| Run Test (Editor)               | Ctrl+U, Ctrl+R |
| Run Tests from current session  | Ctrl+U, Ctrl+Y |
| Run Tests from solution         | Ctrl+U, Ctrl+L |
+---------------------------------+----------------+
```

- Resharper.Resharper_Resharper_UnitTest_DebugContext
- Resharper.Resharper_Resharper_UnitTest_RunContext
- Resharper.Resharper_UnitTest_RunCurrentSession
- Resharper.Resharper_UnitTest_RunSolution

Comment: This is an answer I can understand, almost no sentence, concisely presented in a table

Answer (score 7):

For Resharper 4.5 OOTB:

Unit Test Explorer : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
Unit Test Sessions : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
Close Active Window : <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

I just noticed last week that my keyboard has a right-click button between <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the right side, so no mouse needed to mouse to a specific test. Yeah!

Custom key mapping via [Ben Scheirman's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3381/ben-scheirman) method:
`ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_ContextDebug` : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
`ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_ContextProfile` : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
`ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_ContextRun` : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
`ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunSolution` :  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
`ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunSolution` : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

I find the easiest way to recall these shortcuts is from the menu:

```
Resharper > Unit Tests
```

All the shortcut keys are presented next to each menu item.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [this](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/ReSharper30DefaultKeymap.pdf) short-cut cheatsheet.

BTW, even if there's no default key, you can probably bind one by going to the menu Tools->Options, and then to the sub-category General->Keyboard, and typing ReSharper in the search line.

Comment: OK, Ben Scheirman pointed out exactly what options you are looking for.

Comment: Here's the short-cut cheat sheet for Version 4.0: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper40DefaultKeymap.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Since the time I originally asked this question, this is what I have been using:

**Open 'Unit Test Explorer' and 'Unit Test Session' windows**

- [use the keybindings available in
  ReSharper 4.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175116/are-there-shortcut-keys-for-resharpers-unit-test-runner/870955#870955)

**Selecting a single test in 'Unit Test Session'**

- to select a test, use arrow keys to navigate

**Selecting multiple tests in 'Unit Test Session'**

- to select multiple ***continous*** tests, hold
  the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down while navigating
  with the arrow keys
- to select multiple ***non-continous*** tests,
  hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while using arrows keys
  and toggle `Spacebar` to select/deselect tests

**Run and execute tests in 'Unit Test Session'**

- press context menu button (found
  between the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> buttons
  on most Windows-centric keyboards)

or

- alternatively, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>
- navigate with arrow keys within
  context window and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on any selection

or

- for `Run Selected Tests`, press <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- for `Debug Selected Tests`, press <kbd>D</kbd>

**Select call stack error line hyperlinks**

- if a test fails and the call stack is
  displayed splitting the 'Session'
  window, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate from
  the test section to the error links
  in the lower section
- after tabbing to a specific error line, hit
  <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to line of code with
  the runtime error
- press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> mutliple times as necessary to go backwards
  from the call stack (lower) section back to the unit
  tests (upper) section

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but it's the top SO question on the Google results for the topic, so adding, just in case.

With Resharper V6, it starts with some keyboard mappings setup out of the box:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/08/new-features-in-resharper-6-unit-test-runner/

Answer (score 1):

### RunCurrentSession command

You can collect your tests in a test session tab of *Unit Test Sessions* window. Then you can run all these tests by running command ***ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunCurrentSession***.
*ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTest_RunCurrentSession* command is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in my *Visual Studio*.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no, but I found [this](http://intellij.net/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=277312) forum post

> There are commands listed in the Tools
>   - Options - Keybaord dialog of VS2008 for resharper unit test runner
>
> Resharper.Resharper_UnitTest_ContextRun
>   Resharper.Resharper_UnitTest_RunCurrentSession
>   Resharper.Resharper_UnitTest_RunSolution
>
> Have you tried assigning a keyboard
>   shortcut to these, because I use MSTF
>   and its own test runner, I run all my
>   tests using its shortcut of ctrl r +
>   a, and to run an individual test I
>   either click on the resharper icon (I
>   have Gallio installed) or use test
>   driven.net context menu to run the
>   test.

Answer (score 0):

It writes shortcuts in itself or website.
Run Unit Tests: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>
Debug Unit Tests: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>
Run All Tests From Solution: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
Run Current Session: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>
Repeat Previous Run: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>
Append Tests To Session: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
Create New Session: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd>
Unit Tests: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
Unit Tests Session: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#unit_testing

[image]

Comment: You should also consider adding them in text format to your post

Comment: The picture is already clear and informative, we can look at the shortcut with our Visual Studio ourself.