# ReSharper run all unit tests in a project or solution at once

Tags: c#, resharper

I am inside the IDE and I can run all the unit tests in a file but is there any way to run all test in a project or solution at once?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Right click on the project or solution in the VS solution-explorer and choose 'Run Unit Tests'  Or go to the Resharper menu, choose Unit-Testing and choose one of the options from there.

Comment: In Resharper 7 VS Keyboard mappings it is Ctrl-U,L

Answer (score 26):

If you learn executing menu commands with Alt-Letters, you can execute many commands fast even if they don't have direct shortcuts. Especially, if shortcuts are two-key combos.

As for **run**ning all tests in solution the command is Alt-**RUN**, i.e. Alt-R for ReSharper menu, U for Unit Testing, and N for all tests in solution.

Comment: Except AQtime hijacks Alt-R for its Profile menu

Answer (score 17):

I'm surprised no one mentioned it here, but pretty much all resharper commands can be assigned to specific custom keyboard shortcuts. Go to `Tools --> Options --> Keyboard`, and find the command you're interested (just type "resharper" in the "show commands containing" text field & you'll find them all). In this specific instance, the "Run All Tests from Solution" command is "**ReSharper.UnitTest_RunSolution**".

In ReSharper 9.x, the command name is **ReSharper.ReSharper_UnitTestRunSolution**.

Comment: This is what I do. I have it mapped to control-shift-x. Makes it nice and fast to run all tests.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, but Ilya's ALT+RUN solution over is even better!

Comment: I use `CTRL+T, CTRL+T` to run tests based on context (current test/fixture); `CTRL+T, CTRL+D` to debug based on context; `CTRL+T, CTRL+S` to run tests for the solution & `CTRL+T, CTRL+E` to re-run the existing test session... I find holding `CTRL` & hitting `TT` or `TS` quicker & easier than typing out `RUN` (which needs two hands), but each to their own... (it is cool that they got the menu alt-keys to spell out RUN though).

Comment: @Alconja : What did you replace the original CTRL-T (find type) with? Or do you not use it? CTRL-U is already associated with unit test commands. I would have used that instead...

Comment: @KevinCoulombe - I used IntelliJ IDEA in my pre-.NET Java days and have been on Resharper since the early versions, so I use the "ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA" keyboard shortcut scheme as my base. So find type is CTRL-N, leaving CTRL-T free.

Answer (score 6):

Open ReSharper->Windows->Unit Test Explorer and select everything, then hit the run button

Comment: The unit test explorer only contains tests that you have run in the past. It doesn't have all tests in the solution...

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes, Resharper won't be able to see the tests until you manually rebuild them. So if you can't see the tests in resharper, or resharper isn't running all the tests in the solution, just rebuild them first.

Comment: This turned out to be my problem, thanks. Build-Rebuild (alt+b, r). Then run all tests (ctrl+t, ctrl+l) found them all.

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper 7 default shortcut:](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/docs/ReSharper70DefaultKeymap_VS_scheme.pdf)

Run all tests from solution: <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your unit tests are not fully detected within Unit Test explorer. In that case, restarting Visual Studio helped resolve that problem.