# Visual studio parameterized unit test like java

Tags: c#, java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

In a Java test environment I can use parameterized unit tests as in the following code:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class JunitTest6 {

    private int number;

    public JunitTest6(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void pushTest() {
        System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + number);
    }
}
```

How can I do this in a Visual Studio unit test project? I can`t find any parameterized attribute or any sample like this.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367033/mstest-equivalent-for-nunits-parameterized-tests

Answer (score 10):

Using the [NUnit framework](http://www.nunit.org), you would pass parameters to a test like this:

```
[TestCase(1, 2, 3)]
[TestCase(10, 20, 30)]
public void My_test_method(int first, int second, int third)
{
    // Perform the test
}
```

This will run the two separate times, passing in the values `1, 2, 3` in the first run, and `10, 20, 30` in the second.

Edit: For an overview of available test runners for NUnit, [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336655/what-is-the-best-nunit-test-runner-out-there)

Comment: TestCase attribute is not exits in NUnit or Visual Studio Default Test tool

Comment: Does too! ;) : http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6 Note that this is a different test-framework from the buildt-in one in VS. See the Getting Started guide here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=getStarted&r=2.6 By itself, NUnit-test can not be run directly in VS. There are however, other test-runners that can run them for you. I personally use the Resharper testrunner, and would recommend it if possible. See this for a little more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336655/what-is-the-best-nunit-test-runner-out-there

Answer (score 3):

This is now also possible via the [MSTest 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/01/upgrade-to-mstest-v2/) framework.

It comes with a 'DataTestMethod' attribute and related 'DataRow' attributes. Which makes it similar in how NUnit works.

[Here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2017/03/18/parametrized-tests-with-ms-test/) are some good examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with referencing [NUnit](http://nunit.org/), check out the page for [Parameterized Tests](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5). Support for inline-static and dynamic data values.

If you don't want to use NUnit for some reason, MSTest or VS Unit testing [supports getting inputs from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms182527%28v=vs.100%29) a CSV, XML or DB. Inline support is available via [an extension](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/UnitTestExtendSample). Dynamic support not yet.. you'd have to add the dynamic code to your test method if you want to dynamically compute inputs/outputs.