# Multiple unit test run analysis tool

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, nunit, mstest

Is there any tool that analyzes test reports of particular unit test runs and shows differences between them? Basically, I'm interested in a "graph of progress":

- 12 Aug 2012 10:00: 48/50 tests passed. Failed tests: "MyTest13", "MyTest43".
- 12 Aug 2012 10:02: 47/50 tests passed. "MyTest13" now passed, but "MyTest2" and "MyTest22" started failing.

NUnit is preferrable, however, unit testing framework is not that important.

I'm looking for a completely automated tool, so that I can set it to run it after each build and instantly look at the results and compare them with previous results. The closest thing I've found is [nunit-results](https://launchpad.net/nunit-results) and a hand-written batch file to call NUnit (with specified xml report path) and nunit-results as a post-build action. However, html file that it produces is not that informative.

I'm really surprised that noone of the popular unit testing software is capable of storing test run information and analyzing series of runs in bulk. I've tried Resharper, NUnit GUI, Gallio and haven't found anything useful.

I would be glad for a solution that does not require a setup of a complicated CI server. My projects are typically small, but I need a tool like this for every one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your threshold is for "complicated CI server", but [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) is pretty easy to setup, and with the [NUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin) ought to give you what you're after:

> This plugin makes it possible to import NUnit reports from each build into Jenkins so they are displayed with a trend graph and details about which tests that failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a "Graph of progress", I'd go for a way more simple (IMHO) approach and use [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/). It shows you your tests status as you code, without stopping for test runs. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825301/687857) for more details.